# How can I read the output of the console and put it into a variable?

Tags: c#

I was wondering how i could get the console output and set it to a variable, I have tried using Console.ReadLine() and RedirectStandardOutput but they dont seem to work for me. I am really deboggled here.
Here is the Code that I need help with:

```
Console.WriteLine(JobList[random.Next(JobList.Length)]);

Job = Console.ReadLine();    
switch (Job) {
```

Edit: also this is just a reminder, i am using a console program, so i can't use buttons or anything like that.

Comment: Everything you need to know is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "Deboggled" - thats a new word for me. It's like "boggled" combined with "debugging".

Comment: You really need deboggling. [Start with the basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: I don't know what you are really looking for. If you are trying to create Console and capture all string then probably you need something like this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConsoleAppLauncher/ and you will use something like: return ConsoleApp.Run("yourexe", "/c ver").Output.Trim();

Comment: Are you trying to run another program or trying to capture user input within your own console application?

Comment: You could output everything through a common function and create a log from there. Or is anything but your own code involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm, If I understood your question right, you want to print something to the console, and read it back into a variable.

then that's the wrong way to go about it.. how about this:

`Job = JobList[random.Next(JobList.Length)].ToString();`

Comment: Thank you this is just what I wanted. I am a beginner with c# so I ams till trying to figure things out.